# CardStack Horizontal Viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Hi i'm Making an app where i'm implementing `viewpager` to get a `cardstck` with swipe animation.So for that i found [this](https://github.com/nilsi/CardCarousel) useful project on github.

Now my problem is i'm implementing this project in mine because this is what i want but i'm trying to have `horizontal scrolling` as in this github project it is vertically scrolling.

I tried studying this project but couldn't find a solution to change scrolling from vertically to horizontal.
So please if anyone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

first download library and  user in project don't use by grable because we need to change some  code  in library for as your requirement.

1. CardViewPager.java  file and line 84 : 
   [CardViewPager.java](https://github.com/nilsi/CardCarousel/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nicklasnilsson/cardcarousel/CardViewPager.java)

   setRotation(-90);

   comment this line because this line rotate your view;

Comment: Hello @Kling Klang thanks for response actually i downloaded the app an ran the app as well i noticed that at after scrolling 2-3 minutes the screen goes blank maybe because it is old repository..